# C++: Templating a virtual method with different return types

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-specialization, virtual-functions

I'm trying to write a base class which contains several very similar virtual methods, and I hoped to use templates to reduce the repetition:

```
class CPU {
    template<typename T>
    T getRegister(unsigned int which) {
        /** Returns value of specified register.
         */
        return *(T*)this->getRegisters()[which].data;
    };
    virtual  int16_t getRegister(unsigned int which);
    virtual uint16_t getRegister(unsigned int which);
    virtual  int32_t getRegister(unsigned int which);
    virtual uint32_t getRegister(unsigned int which);
    //etc...
};

class Z80: public CPU: { ... };
Z80 myCPU;
printf("Register 0 = 0x%04X\n", myCPU.getRegister<uint16_t>(0));
```

The goal is for individual CPUs to be able to define their own getRegister() or use the one defined in the `CPU` base class.

I'm not sure exactly what the correct syntax is to make this work, if it's even possible?

Key points that are different from most of the answers I've found:

- The class itself is not a template
- The method is virtual

Comment: You cannot have (virtual) overloads with only difference is the return type.

Comment: What about with different names? Could I provide getRegister<uint32_t>() or getRegister_uint32_t() without repeating the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went looking for a duplicate, but can't find one... I'm sure there is one, but nothing I typed in would find a good one.

C++ doesn't allow two functions with the same signature [1] that has different return types. The compiler NEEDS to know the return type directly from the function signature.

There are a few different ways to solve this particular case:

1) Declare different functions:

```
 virtual  int16_t getRegisterS16(unsigned int which);
 virtual uint16_t getRegisterU16(unsigned int which);
 virtual  int32_t getRegisterS32(unsigned int which);
 virtual uint32_t getRegisterU32(unsigned int which);
```

2) Use an indirect type:

```
virtual void getRegister(unsigned int which, int16_t &value);
virtual void getRegisterU16(unsigned int which, uint16_t &value);
...
```

3) Use a template to have a fixed register size for the CPU:

```
template<typename T>
class CPU {
    T getRegister(unsigned int which) {
      ... 
    }
};
```

I would also make a note here that for 99% of the CPU's operations, signed and unsigned math is the same. It is ONLY compare opeerations that differ [at least in reasonably modern CPU's that you can expect to perform the math for example on a modern x86 or ARM processor, and not simulate each bit individually in simple math steps]

[1] Signature is the name, the argument types and for member functions whether it is `const` or not - I think there may be one or two more things, but those are the main ones.

Comment: Can I do #1 without repeating the function's actual code? i.e. use a template to create several similar methods with different names?

Comment: Not sure. What will actually be different between them - you can always make a basic function that fetches register number `which` and `static_cast` it to the correct type. In the whole scheme of writing a CPU simulator, that is a tiny bit of code.

Comment: (My simple CPU simulator is about 2300 lines, but that's including a simple assembler as well as the simulator itself - but it's only for a single CPU-type, that I invented myself and that is really simple to simulate)

Comment: This is for a debug interface, not part of the actual simulator. The difference would be like shown above, casting to various types. I mainly want to keep the code size small.

Comment: Well, why not just return the 32-bit value always - or know the register size always, like my third example [you can always store the CPU registers as 32- or 64-bit integers still]

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you will still end up with LOTS more code that has nothing to do with how registers are stored/retrieved.